# MQX 4.0.1 program Not Compiled with GCC

Tags: gcc, embedded, arm, codewarrior, mqx

I am using TWR-K20D72M   and I opened a Sample program which is given in the MQX 4.0.1 Demo examples. When I choose Build tool option as  Freescale
the program compiles OK but When I choose Build tool option as GCC It gives me error.The Error is below

error

```
Description 
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target `C:/Freescale/Freescale_MQX_4_0/lib/twrk20d72m.cw10gcc/debug/bsp/intflash.ld', needed by `explicit-dependencies'.
```

I read somewhere  that The GCC can only work with MQX 4.0.1 and above so I am using MQX 4.0.1 .

Can some suggest me the reason for this error.How I can I remove this error.......

Thanks

Comment: You need to figure out what the *makefile* looks like.  Does the tools create a *makefile* from a project?  Certainly, you could supply a *intflash.ld* file.

Comment: `gcc` is only supported on some platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the linker script file for your project `intflash.ld`.

Normally this file is located on

`{mqx_install_dir}\mqx\source\bsp\{your_bsp_name}\gcc_cw`

and is copied to

`{mqx_install_dir}\lib\{your_bsp_name}.cw10gcc\debug\bsp`

and

`{mqx_install_dir}\lib\{your_bsp_name}.cw10gcc\release\bsp`

after the build process by the scripts for your bsp, located on

`{mqx_install_dir}\mqx\build\bat`.

Take a look inside your bsp script and verify that `intflash.ld` is being copied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you compiled your MQX application before compiling the BSP and PSP.  With the release of CodeWarrior 4.6, the solution has gotten a bit easier through the use of .wsd files.

If you look at the FSL_MQX_getting_started.pdf, section 2.4 describes how to find a .wsd file which needs to be dragged into your CodeWarrior Project Explorer.  Once this is done new projects will be added to your workspace.  Compile the bsp_... and psp_... and any other libs that you require (usb, ethernet etc) which will generate binaries and the intflash.ld file in the correct location.

http://cache.freescale.com/files/soft_dev_tools/doc/support_info/FSL_MQX_Getting_Started.pdf